How to vscode configure c_cpp_properties.json to adapt to reference lookup for multiple submodules in a project?
Mainly implement reference lookup and syntax checking
The project structure I maintain now is quite messy, and the project structure is roughly as follows
game_root/
    gss/game/main.cpp
    net/tool1/main.cpp
    net/tool2/main.cpp
    net/tool3/main.cpp
    net/common/ <Here are some common library files>

As you can see, the project has multiple targets, and they now have their own independent makefiles responsible for compilation. If I want to compile the project completely, I need to execute a shell script to execute cd; make; one by one

How do I configure the cpp plug-in to specify their header files separately? Because some header files in the tool are the same, directly configuring {$workspace}/** will result in finding the wrong header file. And they define different macros

For this project structure, what is the recommended vscode configuration method? Maybe it can be used with the makefile-tools plug-in? How to operate?


I tried to configure the configurations array, each target corresponds to a configurations element, such as game, tool1, tool2, and configure includePath and defines respectively. But when I edit the code in tool1, it does not automatically switch the configuration from game to tool1 (when I manually switch in the lower right corner, it works normally)
According to the official documentation, configurations seem to be used for multi-platform support, so what functions are used to support submodules?

you have to write a Makefile that calls the other makefiles, and use the top Makefile in the VSC task

Remember that c_cpp_properties.json is not for compiling your code. Its for Intellisense.

@rioV8 Do you mean to call the Makefiles of all other executable files through a Makefile, so that this top-level Makefile manages all executable files (targets). Then the makefile-tools plugin of vscode can generate all executable files through this Makefile, and then implement Intellisense of cpp plugin through settings like "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"?

@drescherjm Yes I understand that, now I only use it for Intellisense functionality

for intellisense you don't need makefiles or compiling, just place the headers in the right location and tell intellisense where these locations are
